# hide/unhide dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC using C# after selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I have two dropdown lists, one is shown and the other one is hidden by default. I want my 2nd dropdown to be shown only after a particular value is selected from the first dropdown.

My first dropdown - All Items, Document Type

When "Document Type" is selected, 2nd dropdown will appear which is bound from a particular table in the database.

First Drop down

```
@Html.DropDownList("rptOption", new List<SelectListItem>
      {
          new SelectListItem { Text = "Document Type", Value = "DocTyp" },  
          new SelectListItem { Text = "All Items", Value = "allItems" },
      }, "--Select--", new { style = "width:250px; height:40px" })
```

2nd Dropdown which I set hidden by default.

```
<div id="doctype" hidden="hidden">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.tfl_idoctype, "Document Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
@Html.DropDownList("tfl_idoctype", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tfl_idoctype, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

When the user selects "Document Type" from the first dropdown, that's the only type that the 2nd drop down will show.

Comment: You're going to need to use `javascript` and the `onchange` event of the first drop down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this is in `javascript`

```
<script>
  // Get the first dropdown element
  var firstDropdown = document.getElementById('rptOption');
  
  // Get the second dropdown element
  var secondDropdown = document.getElementById('doctype');
  
  // Bind an event handler to the change event of the first dropdown
  firstDropdown.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // Check the selected value of the first dropdown
    if (this.value === 'DocTyp') {
      // If the selected value is 'DocTyp', show the second dropdown
      secondDropdown.hidden = false;
    } else {
      // Otherwise, hide the second dropdown
      secondDropdown.hidden = true;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: OMG, this actually works!!! Thank you so much... I'm a newbie in programming and currently developing my 2nd web application. This is such a big help. Thank you!! :)

Comment: @justsomeone Glad this was helpful :) ... If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.